# uniqueness of chain map for direct sum of

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, direct-sum

I'm trying to show that for the direct sum of two chain complexes $A \bigoplus B$ if we have two chain maps $f_A:A\rightarrow C$ and $f_B:B\rightarrow C$, there should exist a unique chain map $f:A \bigoplus B \rightarrow D$ with the property that $f_A=f \circ \iota_A$ and $f_B=f \circ \iota_B$. The maps $\iota_A,\iota_B$ are the inclusion maps of $A$ and $B$ into $A \bigoplus B$.

I believe we should define $f(a,b)=f_A(a)+f_B(b)$, but I'm not sure why this is unique.

Comment: Try writing $(a,b)\in A\oplus B$ as $\iota_A(a)+\iota_B(b)$.

Comment: @MattCarr so if $p \in A \oplus B$ we can write $p=\iota(a)+\iota(b)$ for some $a,b$ in $A,B$ respectively. Then we define $f(p)=f(\iota(a)+\iota(b))=f_A(a)+f_B(b)$? 

I want to extend this to work for the direct sum of a family of chain complexes so I want to make sure I have the details in this easier case correct.

Comment: If you *had* a map $f$ with $f\iota_A=f_A$ and $f\iota_B=f_B$, then by linearity (I'm assuming you're working in modules or abelian groups) you'd have $f(a,b)=f\iota_A(a)+f\iota_B(b)$ by linearity and so you would have to have $f(a,b)=f_A(a)+f_B(b)$ exactly as you said! This shows that such a map is unique if it exists. Actually, iirc this sort of argument should work in any additive category—$f\circ(\iota_A+\iota_B)=f\iota_A+f\iota_B$ by $\mathbf{Z}$-bilinearity of composition.

Comment: Yes I am working over abelian groups. Sorry I'm abit confused on the linearity note: is it that for any function defined on a direct sum $f:A\oplus B\rightarrow D$ it must be linear in $A$ and $B$, or is it because we require $f\iota_A=f_A$ we get linearity? Apologies I realize this is quite a trivial question but I want to make sure I understand the details.

Comment: It's not a problem. I think I should recant my claim about additive categories since the domains of $\iota_A$ and $\iota_B$ are different. 

But to your question, every element $(a,b)\in A\oplus B$ can be broken up like $(a,0)+(0,b)$, so $f(a,b)=f((a,0)+(0,b))$ since the sum in $A\oplus B$ is defined componentwise. A homomorphism of complexes of abelian groups is linear in the sense that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$.  So if you had a homomorphism of complexes of abelian groups satisfying $f\iota_A=f_A$ and $f\iota_B=f_B$, then the uniqueness is forced by this linearity.

Comment: It's implicit that the unique map should be a map "of the same type." In this case, that type is a homomorphism of complexes of abelian groups.

Comment: Ah thank you, if you copy your second last comment into the answer box I think it would make a good answer to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's implicit that the unique map should be a map "of the same type." In this case, that type is a homomorphism of complexes of abelian groups.